# Deleting rows on multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

Following on from a previous question I asked today - I have modified code written by Roy Cox (Thank you for saving me SO much time!) to create a userform to add, modify and delete users' details in an analysis tool I am creating.

It works perfectly when working with user data on a single worksheet.

Selecting a user and clicking 'delete' deletes their user data on the worksheet. I have modified the code so that when a user is added or deleted, it should check each worksheet and adds or deletes rows accordingly.

This is the code to delete the pupil data on a single sheet:

```
Private Sub cmbDelete_Click()

Dim msgResponse As String    'confirm delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'get user confirmation
msgResponse = MsgBox("This will delete the selected record. Continue?", _
    vbCritical + vbYesNo, "Delete Entry")
Select Case msgResponse    'action dependent on response

Case vbYes
'c has been selected by Find button on UserForm
Set c = ActiveCell
    c.EntireRow.Delete    'remove entry by deleting row

'restore form settings
With Me
    .cmbAmend.Enabled = False    'prevent accidental use
    .cmbDelete.Enabled = False    'prevent accidental use
    .cmbAdd.Enabled = True    'restore use
    'clear form
    Call ClearControls
End With

Case vbNo
Exit Sub    'cancelled
End Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I have tried modifying it to delete the user data on each worksheet, as follows:

```
Private Sub cmbDelete_Click()

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim msgResponse As String    'confirm delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'get user confirmation
msgResponse = MsgBox("This will delete the selected record. Continue?", _
    vbCritical + vbYesNo, "Delete Entry")
Select Case msgResponse    'action dependent on response

Case vbYes
For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
With Sh.UsedRange
    'c has been selected by Find button
    Set c = ActiveCell
        c.EntireRow.Delete    'remove entry by deleting row
End With
Next

'restore form settings
With Me
    .cmbAmend.Enabled = False    'prevent accidental use
    .cmbDelete.Enabled = False    'prevent accidental use
    .cmbAdd.Enabled = True    'restore use
    'clear form
    Call ClearControls
End With

Case vbNo
Exit Sub    'cancelled
End Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

but this version deletes the user's data and the data on the 4 rows beneath them. It does not delete data from the next worksheet at all.

Can anyone offer any advice please?

Comment: 1) you don't seem to have amended your code as per your last given (and accepted) answer. 2) are rows to be deleted in other worksheet the same as in the worksheet where _"the Find button"_ found it?

Comment: 1) You're right - I was being lazy and copied the original post and forgot to amend the code - thank you!

Comment: 2) Yes, the other worksheets will feature the same user lists as each other. The data that is collected on them will vary per worksheet.

Comment: 2) so if row #23 is to be deleted in searched sheet, then all other worksheets row #23 are to be deleted too?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I'm happy to add screenshots if that will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
Case vbYes
    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    With Sh.UsedRange
        'c has been selected by Find button
        Set c = ActiveCell
            c.EntireRow.Delete    'remove entry by deleting row
    End With
    Next
```

to:

```
Case vbYes
    Dim l As Long
    l = ActiveCell.Row 'store currently active cell row
    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Sh.Rows(l).Delete
    Next
```

---

should you ever be interested in knowing why your previous code didn't work:

1)

```
Set c = ActiveCell
```

would set `c` to the currently *active* cell, i.e. the cell your "Find" button selected in the currently *active* sheet

2) while

```
c.EntireRow.Delete
```

would always, quite unsurprisingly, delete `c` *entire row*, i.e. the same row in the sheet where `c` has been found in, since nobody is setting `c` again and point to another sheet range.

and simply looping through Sheets collection doesn't change the *Active* sheet

Comment: Brilliant!Thank you so much - that is perfect.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation as well. I am (perhaps not entirely surprisingly!) learning VBA as I go along and I am sure that I would be a lot quicker once I did some proper training!